# Pageres using PHP exec

Tags: php

I'm using Pageres to capture a Highcharts chart. I have a PHP script that takes in an argument to generate the proper URL and file name for the pageres command. When I go to use PHP's exec command, it fires off a bunch of pageres commands and never actually completes the pageres command. The pageres command works perfectly from the command line though.

Snippet of my PHP code:

```
    $cmd = "pageres http://localurl/wriphp/visGraph.php?port=".$port." 1100x200 --filename ".$port;
    exec($cmd);
```

Why does the php exec call run out of control?

Comment: The answer is to not use pageres and to use wkhtmltopdf library ([wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/))

Comment: wkhtmltopdf requires x server